# Associativity of "in" in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm making a Python parser, and this is *really* confusing me:

```
>>> 1 in [] in 'a'
False

>>> (1 in []) in 'a'
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool

>>> 1 in ([] in 'a')
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

How exactly does `in` work in Python, with regards to associativity, etc.?

Why do no two of these expressions behave the same way?

Comment: You're probably hitting the behaviour described here: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in, the one that lets you write `if a < b < c:` and have it work intuitively

Comment: @millimoose: Yeah, I just never thought of `in` as a "comparison" operator I guess. :\

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`1 in [] in 'a'` is evaluated as `(1 in []) and ([] in 'a')`.¹

Since the first condition (`1 in []`) is `False`, the whole condition is evaluated as `False`; `([] in 'a')` is never actually evaluated, so no error is raised.

We can see how Python executes each statement using the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis("1 in [] in 'a'")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 CONTAINS_OP              0        # `in` is the contains operator
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18        # skip to 18 if the first 
                                                  # comparison is false
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')  # 12-16 are never executed
             14 CONTAINS_OP              0        # so no error here (14)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis("(1 in []) in 'a'")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (())
              4 CONTAINS_OP              0        # perform 1 in []
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')  # now load 'a'
              8 CONTAINS_OP              0        # check if result of (1 in []) is in 'a'
                                                  # throws Error because (False in 'a')
                                                  # is a TypeError
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis("1 in ([] in 'a')")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              6 CONTAINS_OP              0        # perform ([] in 'a'), which is 
                                                  # incorrect, so it throws a TypeError
              8 CONTAINS_OP              0        # if no Error then this would 
                                                  # check if 1 is in the result of ([] in 'a')
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

1. Except that `[]` is only evaluated once. This doesn't matter in this example but if you (for example) replaced `[]` with a function that returned a list, that function would only be called once (at most). [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) explains also this.

Comment: Whoa!! +1 That's amazing, thanks so much! It looks really handy, if only I knew about it! Do you happen to know where this is in the documentation? I [looked](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) but couldn't find anything that suggested this!

Comment: note: `[]` is false, but `[]` is not `False` e.g., `[] and anything` returns `[]` (not `False`).

Comment: I don't understand what's so amazing about this post. You usually shouldn't have to inspect the bytecode to understand what is going on, especially in a trivial situation such as this.

Answer (score 24):

Python does special things with chained comparisons.

The following are evaluated differently:

```
x > y > z   # in this case, if x > y evaluates to true, then
            # the value of y is used, again, and compared with z

(x > y) > z # the parenthesized form, on the other hand, will first
            # evaluate x > y. And, compare the evaluated result
            # with z, which can be "True > z" or "False > z"
```

In both cases though, if the first comparison is `False`, the rest of the statement won't be looked at.

For your particular case,

```
1 in [] in 'a'   # this is false because 1 is not in []

(1 in []) in a   # this gives an error because we are
                 # essentially doing this: False in 'a'

1 in ([] in 'a') # this fails because you cannot do
                 # [] in 'a'
```

Also to demonstrate the first rule above, these are statements that evaluate to True.

```
1 in [1,2] in [4,[1,2]] # But "1 in [4,[1,2]]" is False

2 < 4 > 1               # and note "2 < 1" is also not true
```

Precedence of Python operators: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 11):

[From the documentation:](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

What this means is, that there no associativity in `x in y in z`!

The following are equivalent:

```
1 in  []  in 'a'
# <=>
middle = []
#            False          not evaluated
result = (1 in middle) and (middle in 'a')


(1 in  []) in 'a'
# <=>
lhs = (1 in []) # False
result = lhs in 'a' # False in 'a' - TypeError


1 in  ([] in 'a')
# <=>
rhs = ([] in 'a') # TypeError
result = 1 in rhs
```

Comment: For the first example, they are not completely equivalent. `1 in some_func() in 'a'` will only call `some_func()` once regardless of the result, whereas `(1 in some_func()) and (some_func() in 'a')` will call `some_func` twice if the first comparison returns True.

Comment: @Boris Yeah you're right, they're not equivalent *in general*, I didn't explicitly mention it because it's already contained documentation that I quoted.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer, since the long one is already given several times here and in excellent ways, is that the boolean expression is  **short-circuited**, this is has stopped evaluation when a change of true in false or vice versa cannot happen by further evaluation.

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

It might be a little short (no pun intended) as an answer, but as mentioned, all other explanation is allready done quite well here, but I thought the term deserved to be mentioned.